# Relationship between Chabad and the Malachim today

Tags: chabad, chasidut-hasidism, communities

These days, what is the relationship between Chabad and the [Malachim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malachim_(Hasidic_group))? How close are they -- do members of the groups marry each other, participate in each other's mosdos at all, etc.? Do Chabad consider the Malachim "their own," or members of a totally different group?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7915/are-there-other-extant-chabad-groups-besides-chabad-lubavitch?rq=1

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7915/are-there-other-extant-chabad-groups-besides-chabad-lubavitch?rq=1#comment9981_7923

Comment: I don't remember where I read this, but I believe the Malochim are moving closer to Satmar Chassidus. Either way, their community is very small and insignificant compared to the rest of Chabad.

Comment: @ezra Yes, it seems this way to me too. Of course, Satmar is kind of a catchall for the castoffs/borderlines from every other chassidus

Comment: @ezra I was told quite the contrary - that after the passing of the Maloch the group basically disintegrated and many/most of their members (re)joined Chabad.