# Why was Manhattan Day School (MDS) Founded with the name Yeshivas Ohr Torah in 1943?

Tags: yeshiva-school, jewish-american-history

Would someone know the background of how/why the school got the name ישיבת אור תורה?

Was it just a nice name? Did any of the founders have some affinity to Yeshivas Ohr Torah of Teveria which was founded in 1900 and was fairly well-known in the first half of the 20th century?

See [Morgen Journal Aug. 22, 1943 p. 14](https://www.nli.org.il/en/newspapers/tjm/1943/08/22/01/article/98.2)

[image]

and [Morgen Journal Jan. 28, 1944 p. 16](https://www.nli.org.il/en/newspapers/tjm/1944/01/28/01/article/113.2)

[image]

Comment: Why not just ask them https://www.manhattanday.org/about-mds/contact

Comment: I have considered that and might at some point.  This was not my first line of attack, as the people who work for them now don't necessarily have knowledge of what went on 80 years ago. I have often found that such institutions are so preoccupied with the high-priority tasks of fund-raising and survival that they don't know about their own history.  I have informally asked some people connected with the school in recent decades and they didn't know the answer. Was checking here to see if someone saw evidence in print or possibly was connected to an old-timer who would possess the knowledge.

Comment: Is this question [on topic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? It seems to be asking about Jewish history (i.e. history of the Jewish people, as opposed to history of Judaism).

Comment: I was carefully considering whether to post this on Mi Yodeya and looked at the same  link you just posted and thought that my question was somewhat similar to this on-topic example question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7915